# Booting Ubuntu even if remote share is offline

Tags: mount, samba, umount

In my `/etc/fstab` I use the following:

```
//192.168.5.167/H /mnt/ssd ssd credentials=/root/.smbreds 0 0
```

But in case if the drive on Windows is not connected or Windows machine is not running, Ubuntu containing this `/etc/fstab` won't boot.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider user autofs instead of fstab. AutoFS will mount the share on demand.

Install the requirements with

```
sudo apt install autofs smbclient cifs-utils
```

Add the following line into `/etc/auto.smb`.

```
sudo /cifs  /etc/auto.smb --timeout=300
```

Of course create the folder

```
sudo mkdir /cifs
```

Restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart autofs
```

Create the folder that will contain the credentials

```
mkdir /etc/creds
chmod 600 /etc/creds
```

Create the file `/etc/creds/192.168.5.167` (or servername) and copy the content you currently have into /root/.smbreds. It should look like:

```
username=<smb username>
password=<smb password>
domain=<smb domain>
```

Your share should now be auto-mounted as soon as you do:

```
cd /cifs/192.168.5.167 #Or servername if you changed to servername)
```

You can even create a symbolic link if you need to have to same path than previously

```
umount /mnt/ssd
rmdir /mnt/ssd
ln -s /cifs/192.168.5.167 /mnt/ssd
```

Comment: from where do I get to know the domain ?

Comment: I gave it a try and it didnt work. the remote disk is an ext formatted connected to that computer.

Comment: Where is it failing, can you give more details ? I used to setup several time to remotely mount windows share. Also, domain is optional if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read `man fstab` you will see the next options you could try in your case:

```
noauto do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at
                     boot time)
nofail do not report errors for this device if it does
                     not exist.
```

The next step could be a script in cron that checks host availability and connects your windows share using `mount /mnt/ssd` command.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184266/bash-ping-script-file-for-checking-host-availability) is an example how you could check host availability by script.

Comment: So i can include `nofail ` in the mount command?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I think it will not report errors for the device, but hanging could be present. I did not try it first. If it will not help, than use `noauto` and find out checking host availability script and mount using script. Also try to use ob2's answer.

Comment: ob2's answer didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

> //192.168.5.167/H /mnt/ssd ssd credentials=/root/.smbreds 0 0

Did you mean:

> //192.168.5.167/H /mnt/ssd cifs credentials=/root/.smbreds 0 0

Unmount the share:

```
sudo umount /mnt/ssd
```

Edit fstab and add two more options: **noauto** and **x-systemd.automount**:

```
//192.168.5.167/H /mnt/ssd cifs credentials=/root/.smbreds,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Then do the systemd 2-step:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

**noauto** will prevent that mounting at boot.

**x-systemd.automount** will mount the share when accessed. It will be seamless. Just go to /mnt/ssd and it will mount. You can also add an option to have it unmount when idle if you want.

Comment: when I tried to restart I got thsi error:
`Feb 06 16:35:55 rockpro64 systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems.`
`Feb 06 16:35:55 rockpro64 systemd[1]: Stopping Remote File Systems.`
`Feb 06 16:35:55 rockpro64 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.`
`Feb 06 16:35:55 rockpro64 systemd[1]: remote-fs.target: Job remote-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'`

Comment: can I use `noauto` with `nofail` together ?